# Laravel Eloquent, appends attribute that is same name with the relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

```
<?php 

class Product extends Eloquent {

protected appends = array('category');

  public function category()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Models\Category',
                            'category_id');
  }

}
```

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<?php 

class Product extends Eloquent {

  protected $with = array('category');
  //protected $appends = array('category');

  public function category()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Models\Category',
                            'category_id');
  }

}
```

Define a `$with` property instead of `$appends` property. It is an eager load.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please post your source?

Comment: it is Laravel 4, https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L146 and https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json

Comment: I checked this with Laravel 5.3 and it works. It's amazing how obscure this is. I was starting to think it was a bad practice that no one followed